# linq casting to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a linq query as follow:

```
public static ViewUserDisplayPreferences GetUserDisplayPreferences(int TheUserID)
{

    using ( MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext() )
    {

        var OutputUserDisplayPreferences = from user in TheDC.Users
                                    where user.UserID == TheUserID
                                    select new ViewUserDisplayPreferences
                                    {
                                        UserTimeFormat = user.UserTimeDisplay
                                    };

        return (ViewUserDisplayPreferences)(OutputUserDisplayPreferences);
    }
}
```

For the moment, the object ViewUserDisplayPreferences is defined as follow (more variables will be added later):

```
public class ViewUserDisplayPreferences
{
public string UserTimeFormat { get; set; }
};
```

On the return statement at runtime, I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[ObjectsUsers.ViewUserDisplayPreferences]'
>   to type
>   'ObjectsUsers.ViewUserDisplayPreferences'.]

What's wrong with the code? The intellisense is not showing any error on the line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OutputUserDisplayPreferences` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want an object, use either the `First` (if there can be more than one) or `Single` (if you know for sure only one object will be in the sequence) method on the sequence. If it is possible for the sequence to be empty, use the respective `*OrDefault` method.

Answer (score 3):

Linq returns a collection. Try adding a .FirstOrDefault to the end.

Comment: You read it in books but it comes to make sense later, when you're stuck. Thanks.